# Silverstripe replaces DropdownField with NumericField

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am developing a silverstripe projects with Silverstripe 3.1.3. which generates forms for the website -not the admin section- by calling the function getFrontendFields() on the related DataObjects. "has_one"-relations will be displayed as dropdown field (class: DropdownField) with the entries as options. Everything works fine on my local dev environment, but in the live environment the same fields will be displayed as input (class: NumericField). The only difference is the data. On my local system the field has 5-10 items, in the productive system more than 100.

Does anyone has the same issue? I build a work around, but is there a general solution to this?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235458/silverstripe-admin-has-one-dropdown-converts-to-ordinary-input-field-after-im

Comment: Whoops, I also flagged the image for "This question does not meet this site's standards and should be closed". Lesson: Never do this using your mobile phone...

Comment: All good. Interesting is that I googled before and even the "pre-ask" search didn't come up with the results which are coming up in the "related" block now. I wouldn't have asked it if I would have found it before.

Comment: Ah well, it was my question to begin with, happy that at least my internal search was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. If there's over 100 possibilities for the generated drop down field it will be replaced by a numerical field.

You can replace the numeric field with a dropdown field after it's been scaffolded but there's no easy way to change this behaviour.

Comment: Have you got a link to a bugtracker about this? Or the part of the source code?

Comment: It's not a bug, so doesn't make sense to be in a bug tracker. The code that handles it is [here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/model/fieldtypes/ForeignKey.php#L29-L53).

Comment: This caught me off guard when after some time in production we got numericfield missing setsource method error.