# Searching for relational record in SilverStripe ModelAdmin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have two `DataObject`s named `AosMember` and `Council`.

The `Council` class has a `$has_one` relationship to `AosMember`.

```
class Council extends DataObject {

    public static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Year' => 'Year(4)'
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
        'Member' => 'AosMember'
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'Year',
        'Title'
    );

    private static $searchable_fields = array(
        'Member.LAST_NAME' => 'PartialMatchFilter'
    );
}
```

When I go into the `ModelAdmin` for `Council` in the CMS I see a text input for `Member`. The member count is +500 so ideally I want to be able to type in the last name and get an autocomplete of some kind.

At the very least I would like a drop down field. But I cannot find instructions on how to get either.

Comment: Is Member the default SilverStripe Member DataObject? Would a Council have one Member, never more?

Comment: @RobbieAverill No, The actual name of the DataObject is AosMember, sorry. Each year there are 7 Councilmen. Each titled position has one AosMember by year.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, to clarify, each Coucil row would have only one AOS member associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming that you are letting the model admin to scaffold what editor it should use for managing has one relations.

It would be a dropdown field but if there are more than 100 records in will default to a input field for memory usage purposes see comments on the accepted answer: [Silverstripe admin: "Has one" dropdown converts to ordinary input field after import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235458/silverstripe-admin-has-one-dropdown-converts-to-ordinary-input-field-after-im)

I'd suggest on using these as an alternative way to manage the has-one relation:

- https://github.com/briceburg/silverstripe-pickerfield
- https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-hasonefield
- http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/simonwelsh/hasoneedit

Haven't tested any of them but I'd assume the first one would be the best for your case.

Comment: Thanks FinBoWa.. I had visited that Stack link several times and tried to implement it. Finally today I got it to work. Not sure why it was so hard for me to figure out. I am going to edit your answer and put in the relevant code.

Comment: @silversunhunter I think you shouldn't edit my answer. I'ts good as it is because it answers your issue albeit with links :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Member.ID` to the searchable fields list will make this field an autocomplete dropdown field:

```
class Council extends DataObject {
    // ...

    private static $searchable_fields = array(
        'Member.ID' => array(
            'title' => 'Member',
            'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter'
        )
    );
}
```

The text to search on in the field will be the title of the `AosMember` object. If the `AosMember` doesn't have a title then we can return specific content through a `getTitle` function:

```
class AosMember extends DataObject {
    // ...

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->FirstName . ' ' . $this->LastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This is Great! It gives me the autocomplete in the search area which is close. When I click "Add Council" button it takes me to a form and there is a field for Aos Member as expected. This accepts numbers only which i presume would be the ID of the member. However it does not have the autocomplete search feature. CAn I somehow take what you have and apply it to that field?

Comment: I think I would put the Member.ID array into the model admin. Trying to google a way to do that.

Comment: @silversunhunter I'd suggest on looking at my answer first before googling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give SS some more info in your `$searchable_fields` static and a call to `scaffoldSearchFields()`. Something like this (I ripped this out of one of my own projects, you might need to alter it slightly for your own uses)

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
private static $searchable_fields = array(
    'MyField' => array(
        'title'     => 'Title',
        'field'     => 'DropdownField',
        'filter'    => 'PartialMatchFilter'
    )
);
```

Then you need to instruct SS how to scaffold your searchable Member field:

```
    public function scaffoldSearchFields($_params = null) {
        $fields = parent::scaffoldSearchFields();
        $field = DropdownField::create('MyField','My field search', Member::get()->map()->toArray());
        $fields->replaceField('MyField', $field);

        return $fields;
    }
```

Once it's working, you should see a `DropdownField` in the CMS' centre "filter" pane. N.b. You will prob need some further logic to deal with the `has_one` relation. The above example as-is, will only work for direct fields defined via `$db`.

Comment: I think that Searchable Fields is not what I am looking for. When I create a new Council field for the Member is just a text input. Shouldn't it be allowing me to find an actual member in the database to associate?

Comment: Do you mean Council "field" or Council "object"? Show us the code that you have so far.